# Piping Find and Move Command Output to a file

Tags: linux, find, mv

I'm executing the following command and the output is not going to the 
`move.log` file. Am I missing something in the command?

```
find /db_backups/30_plus_days -type f -mtime +90 -exec mv {} /db_backups/90_plus_days/ >> /db_backups/move.log 2>&1 \;
```

Comment: `mv` (without the `-v` or `--verbose` option) doesn't usually produce standard output - what are you expecting exactly?

Comment: The `find` command, in the way that it is being used here, does nat produce any output.

Comment: That did it. Thanks. Was trying to just generate a record of what files were getting moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `find` command line:

```
find /db_backups/30_plus_days -type f -mtime +90 -exec mv {} /db_backups/90_plus_days/ >> /db_backups/move.log 2>&1 \;
```

is the same as

```
find /db_backups/30_plus_days -type f -mtime +90 -exec mv {} /db_backups/90_plus_days/ \; >>/db_backups/move.log 2>&1
```

The `find` command, when used in this way, will not produce any output at all and therefore no new data will be written to the `move.log` file.

If you wanted to store the names of the files that were moved, add `-print` before the `-exec`:

```
find /db_backups/30_plus_days -type f -mtime +90 -print -exec mv {} /db_backups/90_plus_days/ \; >>/db_backups/move.log 2>&1
```

or, with nicer line-breaks (only for readability):

```
find /db_backups/30_plus_days \
    -type f -mtime +90 -print \
    -exec mv {} /db_backups/90_plus_days/ 2>&1 \; \
    >>/db_backups/move.log
```

Comment: Actually, `-print -exec mv ...` will print the names of the files before the command tries to move them. But doing it the other way around, `-exec mv ... \; -print` will only print them after the move has successfully completed (and will not print if it fails)

Comment: @ilkkachu But if it fails I'd assume that `mv` would say something, which in turn would go into the log.